# Where should I put middle size const Array in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have about 50 words which will never change in the future like this.

```
FRUITS = [
  "Apple",
  "The strawberry",
  "Grapes",
  ...
  ...
  "Kiwi",
  "Grapefruit",
  "Mellon"
]
```

Of course, I can put this to the top of the Class, but the code will be too long..
Do you know the way to manage these kind of middle size const array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all these constants into an YML file.

And in the model/top of class, load it like :

```
FRUITS = YAML.load_file('path/to/file')['FRUITS']
```

The yml file can have all these global constants like fruits,vegetables etc. in your case. Makes it easy to maintain/modify list of all these globally...

Comment: My only comment about YAML would be that for an array (collection) of words, you'll need to put a dash or `-` character before each word/line. Personally, if you won't need more than one set of constants (e.g., only `FRUITS`) then I'd go with `File.readlines('path/to/fruits.txt').map(&:chomp)`

Answer (score 0):

You can put it inside a module:

```
module MyFruitsList
  FRUITS = [
    ...
  ]
end
```

And then include it in your class:

```
class MyClass
  include MyFruitsList
end
```

Comment: That is a terrible advice. Clogging models with useless modules is just bad.